# How to block flows from other nodes on Corda network?

Tags: corda

My dev node is part of the Corda test network, and when I open the logs I see something like (node etc..sent you a flow which you don't have installed, you can kill it with `kill flow`). So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I reject these calls? I know the purpose of being part of the Corda network is to have the ability for CorDapps of different orgs to transact, and I don't want to go with the segregated network model (because it's more expensive for prod and pre-prod Corda nets).
2. Can a node on the network perform a DoS (Denial of Service) attack by sending me flows that I don't have installed and eventually bringing my node down?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm right about my answer but as far as I know Corda Network is designed on a need to know basis and I know that you are aware of it and I was having the same doubt when I first started with Corda but I found out that one can simply block a node from sending you any undesired flows which could cost you unnecessary CPU runtime. [The explanation to this is given in this link.](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-djvm.html#runtime-costing)
Apart from this I have gone through a Medium Post which explained about ResoponderFlow validating information passed through flows and one of the points mentioned over there was to verify the identity of the flow initiator(so as to find if we need that flow),which can't be done within a contract so it needs to be done inside a flow.
Also one can't keep flooding a node with a flow because it contains a timeout,maxRestartCount and backOffBase which really help in determining how the flow is getting propagated across the network.
I hope this helps you to construct a solution to your doubt.

Comment: Sandeep, I don't have that flow installed on my node to check the initiator; it's just some other node on the network starting a flow session with me. Every time they do that, my node has to check that I have the responding flow installed and registered.

Comment: That's the reason you can block the node from reaching you so that you can save the effort of checking for the responding flow to match the initiated flow.Also for some more explanation regarding how the node wouldn't respond to the flow is given in this link.
[link](https://docs.corda.net/node-flow-hospital.html?#run-time-behaviour)
But what I feel is that Corda approaches this problem either by blocking the node which is not right or by using minimalistic methods like the use of Flow Hospital as mentioned in the docs.